# Secret Levels on Yoshi's Island DS

Tags: yoshis-island-ds

On the stage map screen for each world in Yoshi's Island DS, there are 2 levels on the screen that do not get unlocked through regular progression through the levels.

How do you unlock those levels? Do you need a certain total score for the world? Or do you have to collect all of the flowers/red coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret level in each world is unlocked after beating the game. The extra level in each world is unlocked for scoring 100 points on each of the other levels in that world *including* the secret level.